# g++ 4.4 dereference change of const var seg fault

Tags: c++, variables, g++, constants

I am currently porting code from RHEL5 to RHEL6.  Although I don't agree with doing this I am curious why dereferencing a const var and attempting  to update it would cause a segfault in RHEL6 (g++ 4.4) and not RHEL5.

The program is fine without const I am just curious what is special about where a const variable is stored in g++ 4.4

Here is the code and the segfault

```
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const double    kPi = 2.0 * acos(0.0);

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {

(*((double *)&kPi))                     = 2.0 * acos(0.0);

}
```

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x000000000040068e in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd9b8) at helloconst.cpp:11
    11          (*((double *)&kPi))                     = 2.0 * acos(0.0);
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64

```
(gdb) bt 
#0  0x000000000040068e in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd9b8) at helloconst.cpp:11
(gdb) list
6       #include <math.h>
7       using namespace std;
8
9       const double    kPi = 2.0 * acos(0.0);
10      int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
11          (*((double *)&kPi))                     = 2.0 * acos(0.0);
12      }
```

(gdb)

Answer (score 2):

Changing a `const`variable invokes undefined behavior, the compiler can do whatever they want. So there's really nothing to explain, don't do that.